Why do artists make grammar mistakes in their songs?
I would be deeply grateful if you answer my question. I'm currently writing my thesis about standard and non-standard English grammar and the main problem of my work is why artists make grammar "mistakes" in their songs.
Below you can find some examples which I've found. I shily encourage you to explain me how you see this, especially I would be really grateful if some native speakers answered my questions, but of course all answers are welcome.
Justin Timberlake – What goes around
My heart bleeded
Adele – Rumor has it
It don’t mean
Adele – Hello
It don’t matter
The Rolling Stones – Satisfaction
I can’t get no satisfaction
Pink Floyd – Another Brick In The Wall
We don’t need no education
Florida – My house
What we is
The Police – every little thing she does is magic
Everything she do just turns me on
Elvis Presley – Hound dog
When they said you was high classed
Eric Carmen – hungry eyes
I feel the magic between you and I
Red Hot Chili Peppers – snow (hey oh)
Listen _ what I say
The Beatles – come together
He come grooving up slowly/he _ one holly roller/he just do what he please
Katy Perry – dark horse
She eat your heart out like Jeffrey Dahmer/she turn cold as freezer
Miley Cyrus – wrecking ball
I just closed my eyes and swung, left me crashing in a blazing fall (no subject)
Justin Bieber – boyfriend
If I was your boyfriend
James Brown – I feel good
I feel good (an adjective used instead of a adverb)
Timbaland – the way I are
I are
X Ambassadors – unsteady
Cause this house don’t feel like home
Machine Guy & Camilla Cabello – bad things
I’m insane, but you _ the same
Gwen Stefani – rich girl
If I was a rich girl
Ray Parker Jr. – Ghostbusters
Who you gonna call? (instead of Whom are you going to call?)
Tina Turner – what’s love got to do with it
What’s love got to do with it (instead of what does love have to do with it)
Bruno Mars – grenade
Should’ve known you was trouble from the first kiss
Justin Timberlake – Can’t stop the feeling
And ain’t nobody leaving soon / I don’t need no reason
Lady Gaga – bad romance
You and me could write a bad romance
Meghan Trainor – me too
If I was you, I’d wanna be me to
Justin Bieber – love yourself
My mama don’t like you and she likes everyone
Sam Smith - lay me down
Can I lay by your side (difference between lay and lie, it is pronounced as /leɪ/ (lay) but it should be /laɪ/ (lie) – AmE)
Bruno Mars – when I was your man
It don’t sound the same
Justin Bieber – intentions
You don’t need no filter
Sam Smith – unholy
Mommy don’t know daddy’s getting hot
THANK YOU ALL IN ADVANCE

Perhaps is (a) because they don't speak grammatically or (b) they want to appeal to a demographic which likes the lack of correctness in a song. Note that "I can’t get no" and "we don't need no" are widely spoken in the artists' British English.

I’m voting to close this question because the premise of the question is that song lyrics can be submitted to grammatical judgment. They can't. Neither can literature.

I feel good is completely standard English, even if it technically is an adjective and not an adverb. I feel well generally means my health is good. But I feel good means something more like I am happy. See Merriam-Webster.

In song lyrics and poetry, it's often more important to fit the meter and rhyme scheme than to use proper English. Many of your other "mistakes" are common vernacular -- real people don't always use proper grammar in casual speech.

'I feel + [adjective] (hungry / cold / sad / neglected / cold ...)' is a standard depictive construction. Compare standard resultative constructions, 'He became + [adjective] (hungry / cold / sad /cold ...)'. // AAVE doesn't use standard grammar and often appears in songs; hypercorrections appear even on the BBC News (though 'I feel the magic between you and I' would be pushing it) ... and one feels that lyrics receive less proofreading than say dissertations.

Here are many sources that will  give you more than indications (but the resons  have little to do with  grammar): https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Why+is+English+grammar+often+incorrect+in+songs. This is apparently a sociocultural phenomenon, and perhaps you might try some research in the  domain of sociology.

An ear for daily dialogue is a gift songwriters and poets are blessed with. I will quibble with "Hungry eyes: I feel the magic between you and I" as overcorrecting, though. It's like "I feel badly." Or needing a rhyme. But I love "My mama don’t like you and she likes everyone." In that song, "You should go and love yourself" uses the word love delicately to replace the F word that belongs.

Sometimes the writer wants to create a feeling, such as the band name "Barenaked Ladies", which is redundant and the first word should be two, but also sounds like something a little rascally urchin would say.

Because a) They pander to the lowest common denominator b) Their overall education leaves much to be desired.

I'm giving you a +1 and voting to reopen the question. It's a legitimate question.

It's debatable whether "If I was a rich girl" is ungrammatical. Using "was" in place of "were" in the first person is commonly heard in speech.

The grammaticality of "that don't impress me much" and How to interpret the phrase "no more" in "Don't love no more" ? and "A child don't know anything" in Gadsby — grammatically right?

“The reason why don't is is used in that title is that it imitates certain non-standard dialects of English, where don't can be used with the 3rd person singular. It is similar to the way people jocularly use ain't: it has a certain irony and force that can be appropriate for rhetorical or artistic effect”.

Were this question be reopened, it would be closed as a duplicate of the first Q that I included a link to. See this answer on writing

Questions about why artists do something normally belong on Literature SE. It's reasonable to pick an individual form and ask here if it's grammatical in standard English or in non-standard forms of English, or if it has a distinct meaning compared to the standard, but asking about a huge (and rather heterogenous) list isn't practical in the SE format. It's also not good to ask SE to write your thesis without having done any research yourself.
